# Me pueden decir como solucionar el error de estilo que me aparece en jaspersoft

Tags: eclipse, java-8, jasper-reports

**Es la primera vez que uso esta herramienta y me estaba funcionando a la perfección mi impresion de reportes pero de la nada me dejo de funcionar y me aparece un error de Style**

```java
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException:
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: 
Could not resolve style(s): iReport.
```

Comment: puedes especificar un poco los cambios que realizaste??

Comment: solo le modifique el tamaño del DETALLE. copie y pegue en java eclipse

Comment: si sabes que debes exportar los reportes verdad???

Comment: si si, el problema era una linea de código que no debería de estar y no se de donde salio